# Object at index i only showing last image

Tags: objective-c, image, nsarray

In the following method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
```

I currently have 22 of the following:

```
if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Arcadian Winery"]) {
    [profileIconView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arcadian.png"]];
}
if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString: @"Babcock Winery and vineyards"]) {
    [profileIconView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"babcock.png"]];
}
if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Bonny Doon Vineyard"]) {
    [profileIconView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bonnyDoon.png"]];
}
```

I Would like to replace it with the following array but it keeps returning only last object.

```
 NSArray *wineryTitle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"Arcadian Winery",
                       @"Babcock Winery and vineyards",
                       @"Bonny Doon Vineyard",
                       @"Castoro Cellars",
                       @"Dry Creek Vineyard",
                       @"Gary Farrell Wines, Inc.",
                       @"Equinox Methode Champenoise",
                       @"Figge Cellars",
                       @"Frog's Leap Winery",
                       @"Heitz Wine Cellars",
                       @"Kathryn Kennedy",
                       @"Merryvale Vineyards",
                       @"Manzoni Estate Vineyard",
                       @"Marilyn Remark Winery",
                       @"Bernardus Vineyards & Winery",
                       @"Nickel & Nickel",
                       @"Opolo Vineyards, Inc.",
                       @"Riverbench Vineyard and Winery",
                       @"Steven Kent Winery",
                       @"Storrs Winery",
                       @"Talley Vineyards",
                       @"Thomas Fogarty Winery",
                       nil];

NSArray *wineryImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"arcadian.png",
                        @"babcock.png",
                        @"bonnyDoon.png",
                        @"castoro.png",
                        @"dryCreek.png",
                        @"garyFarrell",
                        @"EquinoxMethodeChampenoise.png",
                        @"figge.png",
                        @"frogsLeap.png",
                        @"heitz.png",
                        @"kathrynKennedy.png",
                        @"merryvale.png",
                        @"manzoni.png",
                        @"mailynRemark.png",
                        @"bernardus.png",
                        @"nickelAndNickel.png",
                        @"opolo.png",
                        @"riverbench.png",
                        @"stevenKent.png",
                        @"storrs.png",
                        @"talley.png",
                        @"thomasFogarty.png",
                        nil];

for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {

    UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    if ([[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        [profileIconView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[wineryImage objectAtIndex:i]]];    
    }

    profileIconView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 33);
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
    [profileIconView release];

}

return pinView;
```

The array is looping through the string of titles properly, but always **returning only the last image to the annotation.**

Comment: There's a `-release` call in there. In 2013 you really should be using ARC unless you've got a really good reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is guaranteed to always return the last item because the condition in your `if` statement is always true:

```
if ([[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i]]) {
    [profileIconView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[wineryImage objectAtIndex:i]]];    
}
```

You're comparing `[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i]` to `[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i]`, which always will be true.

Did you mean to compare the `wineryTitle` to, for example, some property of your annotation? For example, if you wanted to use the `title` of the annotation:

```
if ([[wineryTitle objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[annotation title]]) {
    // do something
}
```

Or, if you want to take advantage of the syntax of the new compilers:

```
if ([wineryTitle[i] isEqualToString:[annotation title]]) {
    // do something   
}
```

Thus yielding (putting a little more logic in the `if` block) something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    if ([wineryTitle[i] isEqualToString:[annotation title]]) {
        UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        profileIconView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 33);
        profileIconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:wineryImage[i]];    
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
        [profileIconView release];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: -Nick- Can't us ARC in this case (I have it turned off for only this page) cause I am using some old school page curl that mimics google maps page curl.

Comment: Also, in the original code I am calling the string from the array that is currently in viewDidLoad method. So adding the same array again is probably not the best idea. But styling annotation kind of has to be done in the viewForAnnotation method.

Answer (score 0):

btw your if conditions are all mutually exclusive. Instead of

```
if (...) {
    // ...
}
if (...) {
    // ...
}
if (...) {
    // ...
}
```

*please* do:

```
if (...)  {
    // ...
} else if (...) {
    // ...
} else if (...) {
    // ...
}
```

if you ever really need all this.

It'll reduce your carbon footprint.

In addition, `NSArray` has inspection methods that allow you to return the index of the object you're interested in. For [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest%3a).